# Angular extend vs $provide.decorator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, extending, angular-decorator

I am confused. Could you clarify the difference among **angular.extend()** and **$provide.decorator**? `Why and when use the second one?` Is **decorator** doing something different than **extend**? I cannot find any answer after having performed a search...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`angular.extend()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) is just yet another implementation of the *standard JavaScript extend tool*. You can find many other similar (when not identical) implementations, like [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), [jQuery's](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/), [Underscore's](http://underscorejs.org/#extend)...

[`$provide.decorator()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators) though is the Angular implementation of [the decorator pattern](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Decorator_pattern), and is much more powerful as it allows you to change the behavior of a provider transparently, i.e. without having to modify the dependent objects. The example in the doc is quite straightforward: each time `$log.warn()` is called, the message will be automatically prefixed by `'Decorated Warn: '`.